# How to fill the remains of the background of a page that is partially filled with an image?

Tags: background, fill

I'm creating a report about my latest internship in InDesign where some of my work will fill empty pages. I'm creating various web designs and all of those pages don't have the same ratio as the paper itself, which results in white empty space at both sides.

Let's look at this example from my current document.
[image]

The problem is that I would like to fill the complete page, but I would also like to show the whole result, instead of slicing it into two or only show a half at all, as visible in the next example.

[image]

And there are many more examples where the whole result doesn't fit the whole page and I'm looking for a great general solution and perhaps you got the solution or either some tips getting a great result.

This document specific, I'm using A5 (148mmx210mm) paper.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I think your options are two: You either show a portion of the design, you scale it so it's vertically and horizontally centered (then perhaps fill the background with another color), or you change the size of the columns so your text one is larger than your sample one...

Comment: Although your first suggestion is quite obvious, I do like your second suggestion. Even though in the examples above, you see spreads; text left page, images right page, I could extend the paragraph to the next page and fill up 50% of the width and fill the image completely, as much as possible for the remains of the width. It's not a complete all-time solution, but best so far. I keep this question open, but I gotta say again: I do like your second suggestion! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally try to fill in the white space with the pattern from the dark blue background. You could try to reproduce the pattern itself, but an easy way to come close is just to take one vertical column of pixels on either edge of the blue and stretch it (or duplicate it multiple times) until it fills in all of the white space, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments, I think your best option is to extend the text when the image is narrower.

Something along the lines of:

[image]